# Iterate through a dataframe rows performing multiple calculations and returning "True" or "False"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm new to python so bear with my poor code.

I have a dataframe that contains around 2000 items and in each theres two columns i want to access - "Longitude" & "Latitude".

I then have a list of tuples called RouteNodeLL which contains a list of 600 tuples like ((5.1233,-2.13), (6.342,-3.132), .....)

I need to be to iterate through the dataframe rows and perform the following calculation

(((np.arccos(np.sin((cel1*np.pi/180)) * np.sin((lat*np.pi/180))+np.cos((cel1*np.pi/180)) * np.cos((lat*np.pi/180)) * np.cos(((cel2 - lon )*np.pi/180))))*180/np.pi)*60*1.1515*1.609344)

with cel1 being the first item in the tuple and cel2 being the second item in the tuple.

So for each item in the dataframe I need to perform 600 calculations and then if the answer to the above calculation is below 8 then add a column to that item with "True" and if not then "False"

I have the below code which adds a new column to each item with the result of the calculation but I'm now stuck and don't think this is the best way to approach it

```
def mathy_thing(cel1,cel2,lat,lon):
    return (((np.arccos(np.sin((cel1*np.pi/180)) * np.sin((lat*np.pi/180))+np.cos((cel1*np.pi/180)) * np.cos((lat*np.pi/180)) * np.cos(((cel2 - lon )*np.pi/180))))*180/np.pi)*60*1.1515*1.609344)


for waypointLat, waypointLong in RouteNodeLL:
    df[f'Distance From Node - {waypointLat}, {waypointLong}'] = df.apply(lambda row: mathy_thing(row['Latitude v2'],row['Longitude v2'],waypointLat,waypointLong), axis = 1)
```

Comment: How are the 2000 items (lon, lat) correlated with the 600 tuples? I mean, how do you know which tuple to use for each entry in the dataframe?

Comment: That's the thing, I need to use every tuple on that calculation. so it will be 600 calculations per item..